# Angular format Date as "10 Feb 2014" using culture speciication

Tags: angular

Given the current date:

```
var myDate = new Date()
```

I need to format the current date in this way:

**10 Jun 2014**

I have also to implement localization so for EN the result should be **10 Jun 2014** but for IT the result should be **10 Giu 2014**.

What is the properly way to implement it ?

Thanks to support

Comment: I don't suggest to add redundant npm packages, I think this issue can be handle without package. More packages will cost and you need to maintain their version as well as angular is upgrading fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In module ts file

```
import localeitCH  from '@angular/common/locales/it-CH';    
registerLocaleData(localeitCH);
 providers: [
{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-CH' }  ], //you can try out the other locales as per the need
```

> In html file

```
  <!-- {{today | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}} -->
   {{today | date:'dd MMM yyyy':'':'en-US' | titlecase }} <!-- en-US is the previous(angular) default locale -->
   {{today | date:'dd MMM yyyy' | titlecase }} <!-- have changed to the it-CH , hence need not to mention here-->
   <!--Have used titlecase pipe to display text in title case  -->
```

> In Ts file

```
import { DatePipe,TitleCasePipe  } from '@angular/common';

      today =  Date.now(); // Inside the component class
```

Hope this helps thanks!!!

**Note:** Don't get confused as both gives the same result Apr in both cases [April , Aprile] , try to add M to view month name=> MMMM instead of MMM gives the month name

Answer (score 3):

For getting current date you should declare a variable in you'r .ts file like below

```
public today = Date.now();
```

Then use you'r variable in the HTML file with date pipe like below

```
{{today | date }}
```

> I have also to implement localization so for EN the result should be
>   10 Jun 2014 but for IT the result should be 10 Giu 2014.

For change time zone have a look at 
[Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 1):

```
myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-EN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' });
myDate.toLocaleDateString('it-IT', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' });
```

More about `toLocaleDateString` you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 1):

You can install [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):

```
npm install moment --save
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Next use Moment Multiple Locale Support:

```
moment().format('LL');
```

**HINT:** According to your locale, you have a better format:

```
moment().format('ll');   // 4 avr. 2018 for french locale <br>
moment().format('LL');   // April 4, 2018 for US English <br>
```

Hope I help!